How to look up Access denied in AWS?
I created a couldfront distribution and I get an access denied error.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>EKJDP6E2XYVXCG7A</RequestId>
<HostId>zxIi9s/XlmtD88G6fozk6q5aWzRnHckTa0vsm5WGVHZ2t/MoFnv/OP900WltWM17kB/hePk1UvY=</HostId>
</Error>

How do I look up this error in aws? Cloudtrail does not show anything.

I'd assume this is in front of an S3 bucket?  We'll need some details about your config.

@stdunbar what do you mean, why can i just not look up this error somewhere-

Cloudfront can be in front of S3 buckets, Lamdas, HTTPS endpoints and more.  The error you're showing looks like one I have seen from S3 when there isn't sufficient permission for Cloudfront to read from the bucket.  However there may be other ways to get that error.  So it would be helpful to understand what is behind the distribution.  I'm afraid that it's not quite as straightforward as it could be.
